# Why am I getting "String is not a function"?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do replies on my inbox and I thought it'd be as simple as sending a message. I put my email in for the parameters instead of the `$scope.messageTo` and `$scope.messageFrom`.

Does anyone know where the error is in my code? I don't know what causes the error "string is not a function" and it's not giving me any variable names.

```
// Reply to message
// Console error in browser: TypeError: string is not a function
$scope.reply = function () {
    var msg = $scope.reply;
    console.log('Replying...');
    $scope.message = {
        read: false,
        sender: {
            id: $scope.user.user._id,
            name: $scope.user.user.user.first + " " + $scope.user.user.user.last,
            user: $scope.user.user.user.user
        },
        message: msg,
    };
    Inbox.sendNewMessage($scope.message, 'My Name', 'myemail@gmail.com', 'myemail@gmail.com');
};
```

Update: I think it has to do with calling the $scope.reply function itself. If I delete all the code inside $scope.reply and add a simple console.log('Replying');, it gives me the same error. Here's the code to trigger the reply function:

```
<button data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" href="#direct-messages" ng-click="reply();">Send Reply</button>
```

And here's my ng-model="reply"

```
<textarea Placeholder="Write a reply..." ng-model="reply"></textarea>
```

Comment: Do you know that you can put breakpoints in your code? Its true! In chrome press ctrl+shift+I go to the 'Sources' tab and behold!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
Inbox.sendNewMessage($scope.message, 'My Name', 'myemail@gmail.com', 'myemail@gmail.com');
```

With this:

```
Inbox.sendNewMessage($scope.message.message, 'My Name', 'myemail@gmail.com', 'myemail@gmail.com');
```

And use another name for the variable as it is the same as function name:

```
var msg = $scope.replyMsg;
```